# React add a Route after page has loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-router, react-router-dom

I have an API with a list of names (which could change) I then want to create routes from that list but I keep getting route not found error. However when manually adding the route for a name it works.
How do I add a route after the page has loaded to make it work
This is my code below

```
function App() {
    let json =[]
    fetch(`${baseURL}/applications/`).then(response =>{return response.json();}).then(data =>{json=data})
    console.log("json =", json)
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
              <Routes>
                  <Route path="/" exact element={<ApplicationsList/>}/>
                  <Route path={"/1080p-Lock"} exact element={<ApplicationPage name={"1080p-Lock"}/>}/>
                  {json.map(item => {ReactDOM.render(<Route path={"/" + item} exact element={<ApplicationPage name={item}/>}/>)})}
              </Routes>
          </header>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
}
```

Comment: You need to put your fetch inside a useEffect, and store inside a useState,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The React render function is a synchronous, pure function, it can't wait for asynchronous logic to complete. The `json` value is reset to an empty array each render cycle.

The route mapping only needs to return the `Route` components that need to be rendered, using `ReactDOM` here isn't very valid.

## Solution

Use component state to store the fetched data and a mounting `useEffect` hook to make the fetch request.

```
function App() {
  const [routes, setRoutes] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${baseURL}/applications/`)
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        setRoutes(data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // handle any rejected Promises, etc...
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<ApplicationsList/>}/>
            <Route path={"/1080p-Lock"} element={<ApplicationPage name={"1080p-Lock"}/>}/>
            {routes.map(item => (
              <Route path={"/" + item} element={<ApplicationPage name={item}/>}/>
            ))}
          </Routes>
        </header>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```